# Runtime Error 13 - Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm new at VBA coding and working on a match code. The code is working just fine when I run the code in "Data sheet" (the sheet were all my data is and were the match has to be found), but when i'm run the code on the frontpage (Sheet 1 with userforms) the code is debuggen and says "Runtime Error 13". Can anybody tell what the problem is?

And can anybody tell me why my "If isError" doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Br

```
'Find SKU and Test number
Dim icol As Integer


Sheet13.Range("XFD2") = UserForm2.ComboBox1.Value  'Sættes = ComboBox1.value
Sheet13.Range("XFD3") = UserForm2.ComboBox2.Value   'Sættes = ComboBox2.value



icol = [Sheet13.MATCH(XFD2&XFD3,A:A&Q:Q,0)] 'Match af værdien for vores SKU og test nr


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data sheet")



'If SKU or Test number not found, then messagebox
 If IsError("A:A") Then MsgBox "SKU not found": Exit Sub
 If IsError("Q:Q") Then MsgBox "Test number not found": Exit Sub


  'Add test result/next step and comment
  .Cells(icol, 30).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
  .Cells(icol, 30 + 1).Value = Me.Comments_To_Result.Value



End With


End If

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set openDialog = Nothing

Range("XFD2").Clear
Range("XFD3").Clear
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Oh sorry. It is on:
icol = [Sheet13.MATCH(XFD2&XFD3,A:A&Q:Q,0)] 'Match af værdien for vores SKU og test nr

Comment: You declared `icol` as `Integer` and the return of `[Sheet13.MATCH(XFD2&XFD3,A:A&Q:Q,0)]` is not an integer, this is why you get a [`Type mismatch (Error 13)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`icol` should be like this:

`icol = Application.match(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

See the samples in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel):

```
var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(1), 0)
```

---

Concerning  `If IsError("A:A") Then MsgBox "SKU not found": Exit Sub`, you are doing it wrongly. I assume, that you want to loop through all the cells in the first column and to get whether one of them is an error. You need a loop for this. This is a really simple one, but you should implement it somehow in your code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("A:A")
        If IsError(rng) Then Debug.Print rng.Address
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: If i use icol = Application.Match("XFD2" & "XFD3", "A:A" & "Q:Q", 0) the code debugs with error 13 again in this line:.Cells(icol, 30).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value

Comment: @broder123  you have about 2 critical erros in your formula. Read again the MSDN link and try to replicate it. Something like this works: `icol =Application.Match(Range("A2"), range("B:B"), 0)`

Comment: Can you point out the errros? I tried to find them, but can't figure this code...

Comment: @broder123 - compare the sample code in my comment with the sample code in your comment. The erros are there - passing ranges, passing multiple line ranges, etc.

Comment: Ok. I can't figure it out, it keeps debuggen.... Thank you for your time.

Comment: @broder123 - you give wrong Ranges in your comment... `"XFD2&XFD3"` is a string, not a range.

Comment: I think i tried to change everything in my code, also the range as you say, but without luck..

Comment: Could you give me an example for this change? @Vityata